# Using Sentence-Bert with other features in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, embedding, bert-language-model

I have a dataset, one feature is text and 4 more features. Sentence-Bert vectorizer transforms text data into tensors. I can use these sparse matrices directly with a machine learning classifier. Can I replace the text column with tensors? And, how can I train the model. The code below is how I transform the text into vectors.

```
model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/LaBSE')
sentence_embeddings = model.encode(X_train['tweet'], convert_to_tensor=True, show_progress_bar=True)
sentence_embeddings1 = model.encode(X_test['tweet'], convert_to_tensor=True, show_progress_bar=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume this is your data

```
X_train = pd.DataFrame({
    'tweet':['foo', 'foo', 'bar'],
    'feature1':[1, 1, 0],
    'feature2':[1, 0, 1],
})
y_train = [1, 1, 0]
```

and you are willing to use it with `sklearn` API (cross-validation, pipeline, grid-search, and so on). There is a utility named `ColumnTransformer` which can map pandas data frames to the desired data using user-defined arbitrary functions! what you have to do is define a function and create an official `sklearn.transformer` from it.

```
model = SentenceTransformer('mrm8488/bert-tiny-finetuned-squadv2') # model named is changed for time and computation gians :)
embedder = FunctionTransformer(lambda item:model.encode(item, convert_to_tensor=True, show_progress_bar=False).detach().cpu().numpy())
```

After that, you would be able to use the transformer like any other transformer and map your text column into semantic space, like:

```
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('embedder', embedder, 'tweet')],
    remainder='passthrough'
    )
X_train = preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train) # X_train.shape => (len(df), your_transformer_model_hidden_dim + your_features_count)
```

`X_train` would be the data you wanted. It's proper to use with `sklearn` ecosystem.

```
gnb = GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

output:
`GaussianNB(priors=None, var_smoothing=1e-09)`

**caveat**: Numerical features and the tweets embeddings should belong to the same **SCALE** otherwise some would dominate others and degrade the performance

Comment: Dropping it here in case someone else faced the same issue.
I couldn't make it work with multiple columns for ColumnTransformer.
So, I used multiple transformers like this:
`transformers=[('embedder1', embedder, col1), ('embedder2', embedder, col2)],`

Comment: Also, using lambda function creates issue while saving model.
So, I used an alternative approach for the Function Transformer.

```def encode_function(x):
    return sentence_model.encode(x, convert_to_tensor=True, show_progress_bar=True).detach().cpu().numpy()  

embedder = FunctionTransformer(encode_function)```

Comment: Any reason you chose `GaussianNB`?

Comment: No, there is not @rjurney